# Refresh global variable in while loop

Tags: c#, while-loop, global-variables

So I got global variables which are changed by the SerialPort.DataReceived Event. They are updated every 100ms.
Now in another method I have a while-loop doing stuff corresponding these variables. But while inside this loop no changes of the variables will be noticed.
I debuged the variables and printing them on my form; they are changed during the while-loop, but the loop itself dont get it.

```
struct position
    {
        public ushort value;
        public int overflow;
        public int steps;
    }

position actual,
         target;
int Error;



private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ProtIn.read(serialPort1))
        {
            switch (ProtIn.command)
            {
                case "80":
                    actual.value = ProtIn.data;
                    break;

                case "69":
                    Error = ProtIn.data;
                    break;
            }
          Invoke(new MethodInvoker(update_ui));
          }
    }



private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int steps = 45000;
        drive_lock = false;
        do
        {
            if (steps > 32760)
            {
                drive_lock = true;
                if (steps > 0)
                {
                    target.value = (ushort)(actual.value + 32760);
                    steps -= 32760;
                }
                else
                {
                    target.value = (ushort)(actual.value - 32760);
                    steps += 32760;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                drive_lock = false;
                target.value = (ushort)(actual.value + steps);
            }

            ProtOut.build('G', target.value.ToString());
            ProtOut.send(serialPort1);

            if (drive_lock)
                while ((Error & 0xE0) >> 5 != 0)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(200);
                }
        } while (drive_lock);
    }

private void update_ui()
    {
        richTextBox1.AppendText(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(ProtIn.in_buff) + Environment.NewLine);

        tBox_actual.Text = actual.value.ToString();
        txtBox_overflow_actual.Text = actual.overflow.ToString();

        if ((Error & 0xE0) >> 5 != 0)
            lbl_motion.Text = "Moving";
        else
            lbl_motion.Text = "Standing";

    }
```

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: Added code. Hopefully you can get it. It is some work in progress and getting bigger and bigger...

Comment: Which thread executes the serial port callback (`serialPort1_DataReceived`)? Could it be that you're blocking the UI thread with your loop so that the serial port data messages never reach your application?

Comment: try declaring the variables as `volatile`

Comment: Afaik the `serialPort1_DataReceived` will be executed in a backgroundworker thread managed by the compiler or something. Thats why I have to Invoke when I want to contact the UI thread and and show the variables in the form. I will add a line of code in a second.

Comment: @thumbmunkeys does nothing sadly... I think somehow the `while` blocks a refresh.

Comment: Btw, you shouldn't be blocking/polling the way you do now. The `Thread.Sleep(200);` can be replaced by a `Timer`, or you can directly react to the data event you want to handle. Both approaches would be more event-based, which is what windows applications are supposed to be.

Comment: @HannoBinder Problem is that I control a Microcontroller which controls a TMC222 Chip which controls a stepper motor. So the hole project is not the best way to do, but I have to. I know `Thread.Sleep(200);` is not the best way to go, but I would be glad if any way would work :)

Comment: @JonList Yeah so I call the `while` now inside a `backgroundWorker1_DoWork` but nothing changes. Seems so that I have to take a hole other route for this problem.

Comment: Also, I think you may have a bug there: `if (steps > 32760) { ... if (steps > 0) { ...` - the 2nd `if` is *always* true, so the corresponding `else` will never run, while the `drive_lock = false;` part will run for *every* value of steps <= 32760 including 0 and negatives.

Comment: Can't you move the code from `button1_Click` to `serialPort1_DataReceived`?

Comment: @HannoBinder Yes there something like `if((abs)steps > 32760)` needs to be added. No I just can't move the `button1_Click` to `serialPort1_DataReceived`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest something along these lines:

```
struct position
    {
        public ushort value;
        public int overflow;
        public int steps;
    }

position actual,
         target;
int Error;

int steps;

private bool isMoving() {
  return ((Error & 0xE0) >> 5 != 0);
}

private void moveIt() {

    if ( steps == 0 ) {
      return; // Nothing to do.
    }

    if ( isMoving() ) {
      // Still moving, do nothing.
      return;
    }

    if (steps > 32760)
    {
        drive_lock = true;
        if (steps > 0)
        {
            target.value = (ushort)(actual.value + 32760);
            steps -= 32760;
        }
        else
        {
            target.value = (ushort)(actual.value - 32760);
            steps += 32760;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        drive_lock = false;
        target.value = (ushort)(actual.value + steps);
    }

    ProtOut.build('G', target.value.ToString());
    ProtOut.send(serialPort1);

}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        steps = 45000;
        drive_lock = false;
        moveIt();
}

private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    if (ProtIn.read(serialPort1))
    {
        switch (ProtIn.command)
        {
            case "80":
                actual.value = ProtIn.data;
                break;

            case "69":
                Error = ProtIn.data;

                moveIt(); // <<====             

                break;
        }

        Invoke(new MethodInvoker(update_ui));

      }
}



private void update_ui()
    {
        richTextBox1.AppendText(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(ProtIn.in_buff) + Environment.NewLine);

        tBox_actual.Text = actual.value.ToString();
        txtBox_overflow_actual.Text = actual.overflow.ToString();

        if ((Error & 0xE0) >> 5 != 0)
            lbl_motion.Text = "Moving";
        else
            lbl_motion.Text = "Standing";

    }
```

(Give or take some synchronization in case there actually are multiple threads involved.)

Notice that we call `moveIt()` whenever we need some control output generated. This is the case when we first start the routine (via button1), and after that only when the `Error` value actually changes, which we detect synchronously immediately after the data has been received from the port.

Comment: As I mentioned, I can not call `moveIt()` on every `serialPort1_DataReceived` event. I am trying a hole other way now. Without the `serialPort1_DataReceived` event and with manual call of `ProtIn.read(serialPort1)`.

Comment: "I can not call moveIt() on every serialPort1_DataReceived event" - And I cannot see why you shouldn't be able to do so. To me it looks like my code does exactly what yours does, just without the (random) delay of 0~200ms for the next move command.